# Fire event at changing refcount in PHP

Tags: php, scope, automatic-ref-counting, ownership-semantics

When refcount = 0, the __destruct magic method is called. Is there any way to catch the fact that refcount is decreased or increased, but not zero?

A use-case for such an event is to detect if an object is being shared (refcount > 1) or owned (refcount = 1).

**Edit**: Seems like not. A possible solution would be to add two new magic methods to PHP: __owned and __shared. The we would have methods for when refcount = 0 (destruct), refcount = 1 (owned) and refcount > 1 (shared). I will discuss with PHP internals.

Comment: I could not find any hook for that refering to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without a custom extension. Refcount is changed in a lot of places in PHP source code. To add an event there would probably slow down the language.

For more info, search for `GC_ADDREF(object);` in the PHP source.